# How to require implementation of method in Python?

Tags: python, duck-typing, abstract-methods

I'm using duck typing in Python.

```
def flagItem(object_to_flag, account_flagging, flag_type, is_flagged):
    if flag_type == Flags.OFFENSIVE:
        object_to_flag.is_offensive=is_flagged
    elif flag_type == Flags.SPAM:
        object_to_flag.is_spam=is_flagged
    object_to_flag.is_active=(not is_flagged)
    object_to_flag.cleanup()
    return object_to_flag.put()
```

Where different objects are passed in as `object_to_flag`, all of which have `is_active`, `is_spam`, `is_offensive` attributes.  They also happen to have a `cleanup()` method.

The objects I'm passing in all have the same base class (they're db objects in Google App Engine):

```
class User(db.Model):
    ...
    is_active = db.BooleanProperty(default = True)
    is_spam = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    is_offensive = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    def cleanup():
        pass

class Post(db.Model):
    ...
    is_active = db.BooleanProperty(default = True)
    is_spam = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    is_offensive = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    def cleanup():
        pass
```

How can I make the `cleanup()` method abstract so that I can have the same parent class for all these objects that requires the children provide implementation?

Perhaps more importantly, is this 'pythonic'?  Should I go this route, or should I just rely on the duck typing?  My background is in Java and I'm trying to learn the Python way of doing things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have abc available, you can do this with a simple metaclass

```
class Abstract(type(db.Model)):
    def __new__(metacls, clsname, bases, clsdict):
        for methodname in clsdict.pop('_abstract_methods_', []):
            try:
                if not callable(clsdict[methodname]):
                    raise TypeError("{0} must implement {1}".format(clcname, methodname))
            except KeyError:
                raise TypeError("{0} must implement {1}".format(clcname, methodname))
       return super(Abstract, metacls).__new__(metacls, clsname, bases, clsdict)


class RequireCleanup(db.Model):
    __metaclass__ = Abstract
    _abstract_methods_ = ['cleanup']

    def cleanup(self):
        pass
```

the expression `type(db.Model)` resolves to whatever metaclass gets used for `db.Model` so we don't step on google's code. Also, we pop `_abstract_methods_` out of the class dictionary before it get's passed to google's `__new__` method so that we don't break anything. If `db.Model` already has an attribute with that name, then you will need to change it to something else.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `abc` [module](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html). Specifically, set your base class's metaclass to `ABCMeta` and use the `@abstractmethod` decorator on your `cleanup` method.

The debate on whether this is "pythonic" is split. [PEP 3119](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/), which describes the standard, lists some of the pros and cons (but obviously favors ABCs). It made it into the standard library, which is a pretty good indication that many people consider it useful in some circumstances. In your case, I think it is appropriate.

Comment: I don't think it's available on app-engine. It's introduced in 2.6 and app-engine is, last I heard, on 2.5

Comment: Ahh I didn't know that. In that case, the old way (just document it) is probably sufficient.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: When someone proposed using GAE for a project, I was afraid of being stuck with whatever old versions of things Google decided to expose, and so didn't use it--if it's really still on 2.5 in 2010 (or even 2009), I'm very glad I avoided it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that the cleanup method is implemented, you can wrap with the `@abc.virtualmethod` decorator.  This will cause an error on instantiation of any object that hasn't overridden the virtualmethod.  This also requires that you make `abc.ABCMeta` your class's `__metaclass__`.

See the [abc module](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html) for more info and some examples.

This is not commonly done: usually there will just be docs to the effect that implementers must override the given method.  However this may be more due to the newness of the `abc` module (new in Python 2.6) than a perceived unpythonicness of this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have the `cleanup` method just raise an `NotImplementedError` when it is called?  If they want your children classes to work they'll have to put some sort of implementation in place.

Comment: Works well except if overriding methods are to call `super`.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth I thought that was the point. @intuited that's true.

Comment: I can't use cooperative multiple inheritance when subclassing a class that does this because it breaks super. You call super so that the _sibling_ class' method runs. The correct thing to do is define the method with a `pass` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've never used it personally, I've seen many references to [Zope interfaces](http://docs.zope.org/zope3/Book/ifaceschema/interface/show.html). This may be overkill for your task, but it may give you some direction. And it may feel comfortable to someone with a Java background.